# How to make windows 10 re open multiple previously simultaneously closed windows of the same application

Tags: windows-10

I've just migrated from Windows 7 to Windows 10 Pro. I installed the exact same version of Jetbrains Rider. Back on Windows 7 I used to have multiple Rider windows of source files open -all from the same project. When I finished working in Rider, I would always just right click on the task bar and select 'Close all windows' to close Rider. If I launched Rider again that day or the next, Windows 7 would launch Rider by opening all windows that were open in the previous 'session'.

Windows 10 though, does not do this -launch Rider with previous session windows opened. It's not a feature native to Rider either -I asked on the jetbrains forums, so it may have been offered by Windows 7.

That said, how would one go about making Windows 10 remember window instances of an application -Rider in this case?

Comment: Windows can only start a program. How many files or windows it opens is not decided by Windows. I would assume you did not migrate your user data/registry entries correctly so that Rider now behaves differently.

Comment: @Robert What's weird is I've always used Rider's default settings ever since installing it on Windows 7. I uninstalled/installed Rider on Windows 10 the moment I noticed it didn't launch with all prior windows. I guess there's nothing to be done.